# adding custom attributes to fabricjs object

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

Im trying to add a custom attribute to a fabric js object that i have:

```
var trimLine = new fabric.Rect({
    width: Math.round(obj.box_dimensions.box.width,2),
    height: Math.round(obj.box_dimensions.box.height,2),
    strokeWidth: 1,
    stroke: 'rgb(255,2,2)',
    fill: '',
    selectable: false
});
```

so thats my rectangle im trying to add and i want to pass a name or id in it to be able to identify it later when i get the canvas object and convert it to a json.

I have tried doing

```
var trimLine = new fabric.Rect({
    width: Math.round(obj.box_dimensions.box.width,2),
    height: Math.round(obj.box_dimensions.box.height,2),
    strokeWidth: 1,
    stroke: 'rgb(255,2,2)',
    fill: '',
    selectable: false,
    name: trimLine
});

canvas.add(trimLine);
canvas.renderAll();
```

and it did not work i also tried to do

```
 trimline.name = 'trimLine'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For those that run into the same issue the way i solved this is by doing the following:

```
            var trimLine = new fabric.Rect({
                width: Math.round(obj.box_dimensions.trimbox.width,2),
                height: Math.round(obj.box_dimensions.trimbox.height,2),
                strokeWidth: 1,
                stroke: 'rgb(255,2,2)',
                fill: '',
                selectable: false
            });
```

right below it i added this code:

```
           trimLine.toObject = function() {
                return {
                    name: 'trimline'
                };
            };

      canvas.add(trimLine);
      canvas.renderAll();
```

So now when i convert the canvas to a json the trimline object only returns the name which is all i need. Of course you can also add any other info you need as well.

Comment: is it possible to remove the custom attribute from the object later?

Comment: How do you read the custom attribute?

Answer (score 7):

`name:trimLine` should be `name:"trimLine"` unless you have previously declared a `var trimLine='myTrimLineName'`.

FabricJS has many attached properties, including the `name` property.

To avoid overwriting these native properties, add a sub-property to indicate these are your own custom properties:

```
// example: using .my to hold your own custom properties
trimLine.my.name='trimLine';
trimLine.my.id='myOwnID15';
trimLine.my.sayName=function(){alert(this.my.name);}
```

Answer (score 5):

Found a simple solution if your custom attribute is inside a variable,

```
var oText = new fabric.IText(text, { 
    left: 100, 
    top: 100 ,
    transparentCorners: false
    });

var attribute = 'my_attribute';
var value = 'first_name';

oText[attribute] = value;

canvas.add(oText);
canvas.renderAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's old but this works on version 2.2.3

```
var trimLine = new fabric.Rect({
                width: Math.round(obj.box_dimensions.trimbox.width,2),
                height: Math.round(obj.box_dimensions.trimbox.height,2),
                strokeWidth: 1,
                stroke: 'rgb(255,2,2)',
                fill: '',
                selectable: false
            });

let obj={hello:'World'};
trimLine.set('helloworld',obj);
```

then you can get the object

```
  var myObj = e.target.get('helloworld');
```

Answer (score 0):

As per fabric js latest documentation, we can extend object representation with our own property along with it's already existing properties.

```
var rect = new fabric.Rect();

rect.toObject = (function(toObject) {
  return function() {
    return fabric.util.object.extend(toObject.call(this), {
      name: this.name
    });
  };
})(rect.toObject);

canvas.add(rect);

rect.name = 'trololo';

console.log(JSON.stringify(canvas));
```

Source - http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-3

Answer (score 0):

If You use **Fabric.js v5** (v5.3) with **`TypeScript`** or **`Angular`**, and you wish to store custom attributes in Fabric.js Drawing Object, you can achieve it as follows:

```
// Create a rectangle
const rect = new fabric.Rect({
  left: 100,
  top: 100,
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  fill: 'red'
});

rect.toObject = function(this: fabric.Rect, propertiesToInclude) {
  return fabric.util.object.extend(fabric.Rect.prototype.toObject.call(this, propertiesToInclude), {
    name: 'some name'
  });
};

this.canvas.add(rect);
```

---

```
// If you wish to add custom attributes using a separate method, you can do it as follows:

/**
 * Adds a custom attribute to a Fabric.js object when serializing to JSON.
 *
 * @param fabricObject - The Fabric.js object to which the custom attribute should be added.
 * @param attributeName - The name of the custom attribute.
 * @param attributeValue - The value of the custom attribute.
 * @returns The Fabric.js object with the custom attribute added.
 */
addCustomAttribute(fabricObject: fabric.Object, attributeName: string, attributeValue: string) {
    /* fabricObject.toObject = function(this: fabric.Rect, propertiesToInclude) {
      return fabric.util.object.extend(fabric.Rect.prototype.toObject.call(this, propertiesToInclude), {
        [attributeName]: attributeValue
      });
    }; */  

  fabricObject.toObject = (function (originalToObject) {
    return function (this: fabric.Object, propertiesToInclude) {
      const customAttributes = {
        [attributeName]: attributeValue
      };
      return fabric.util.object.extend(originalToObject.call(this, propertiesToInclude), customAttributes);
    };
  })(fabricObject.toObject);

  return fabricObject;
}
```

---

Additionally, you can export saved data as JSON data by using the `toJSON()` method. In Fabric.js v5.3, it exports custom attributes in the object. However, if you're not getting custom attributes in the exported JSON object, you can pass the custom attribute names as an array to the `toJSON()` method:

```js
canvas.toJSON(['myCustomAttr', 'name', 'ownType']);
```

This will include the specified custom attributes in the exported JSON data.

for more reference

1. [fabric.js - Adding custom properties to a shape](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58625733/14344959)
2. https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/issues/6917#issuecomment-792463545

I hope this helps!