# setting a value on object member in fabric.js

Tags: fabricjs

Following advice from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30336983/adding-custom-attributes-to-fabricjs-object) I keep custom attributes in a central place using a `_data` object. 
Setting attributes using set doesn't work like expected.

```
var opts = {
    'width': 200,
    'height': 200,
    _data:{'key':'oldvalue'}
};
var rect = new fabric.Rect(opts);
rect.set('_data.key', 'newvalue') 
//rect.get('_data.key') will still return 'oldvalue'
```

It seems obvious that set uses _data.key as string - but is there any other way?
Of course i can do rec._data.key = 'newvalue'...
using this approach for now:

```
var _data = rect.get('_data')
_data.key = 'newvalue'
rect.set('_data', _data)
```

Comment: I'd say that is working as expected. The final `rect.set('_data', _data)` is unnecessary

Comment: thx, got it. thought there might be a distinct method for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any key name in a fabric object set method. But in a typescript project the editor will complain because the interfaces for the Object class don't have these properties.

The interface "Object" extends the interface "IObjectOptions", which includes the properties that belong to the fabric base Object. There are two properties (name and data) that can be used to add custom properties. name must be a string, and data can be anything.

Here's the snippet within the IObjectOptions interface:

```
/**
 * Not used by fabric, just for convenience
 */
name?: string;

/**
 * Not used by fabric, just for convenience
 */
data?: any;
```

Example:

```
rect.set('name', 'myname');

rect.set('data', {
  'key1':'value1',
  'key2':'value2',
  'key3':'value3'
});
```