# fabric.js - Adding custom properties to a shape

Tags: fabricjs

I am trying to add some custom properties for a rectangle.

I have tried setting the toObject property as per the fabric.js documentation.

```
let rect = new fabric.Rect();

    rect.toObject = ((toObject) => {
        return () => {
            return fabric.util.object.extend(toObject.call(this), {
                name: 'some name'
            });
        };
    })(rect.toObject);

    this.canvas.add(rect);
```

When I click on save of the canvas

this.canvas.toJSON();

I am getting a 
ERROR TypeError: this.callSuper is not a function.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49650667/14344959

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `this` value is not proper inside arrow function. Either change it to normal function, or pass `rect object` instead `this`.

```js
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c')
const rect = new fabric.Rect();

rect.toObject = (function(toObject) {
  return function(propertiesToInclude) {
    return fabric.util.object.extend(toObject.call(this, propertiesToInclude), {
      name: 'some name'
    });
  };
})(rect.toObject);

canvas.add(rect);
console.log(canvas.toJSON())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.4.0/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id='c'></canvas>
```